# sort_values function in pandas dataframe not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset of 1281695 rows and 4 columns in which I have 6 years of monthly data from 2013 to 2019. So, it's obvious to have repeated dates in the dataset. I want to arrange data as dates in ascending order like Jan 2013, Feb 2013,..Dec 2013, Jan 2014,......Dec 2019(6 years of data).I want to achieve ascending order for all of the dataset but it shows ascending order for some data and random order for the remaining data.

I tried sort_values of pandas library.

I tried something like this :

```
data = df.sort_values(['SKU', 'Region', 'FMonth'], axis=0, ascending=[False, True, True]).reset_index()
```

where SKU, Region, FMonth are my independent variables. FMonth is the date variable.

And the code arranges the starting of data but not the end of data. Like when I tried:

```
data.head()
```

result:

```
    index            SKU       Region     FMonth       sh

 0   8264  855019.133127  3975.495636 2013-01-01  67640.0

 1  20022  855019.133127  3975.495636 2013-02-01  73320.0

 2  31972  855019.133127  3975.495636 2013-03-01  86320.0

 3  43897  855019.133127  3975.495636 2013-04-01  98040.0

 4  55642  855019.133127  3975.495636 2013-05-01  73240.0
```

And,

```
data.tail()
```

result:

```
     index       SKU      Region        FMonth       sh

 1281690     766746    0.000087    7187.170501   2017-03-01      0.0

 1281691     881816    0.000087    7187.170501   2017-09-01      0.0

 1281692     980113    0.000087    7187.170501   2018-02-01      0.0

 1281693     1020502   0.000087    7187.170501   2018-04-01      0.0

 1281694     1249130   0.000087    7187.170501   2019-03-01      0.0
```

where 'sh' is my dependent variable.

Data is not really attractive but please focus on FMonth(date) column only.

As we can see the last rows are not arranged in ascending order but the starting rows are arranged in specified order. And if I change the ascending attribute of FMonth column in the above code, means in descending order the data shows the order in the starting rows but not in the last rows.
What am I doing wrong? What to do to achieve ascending order in all of the dataset? And what is happening and why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to prioritize Month?

```
z = pd.read_clipboard()
z.columns = [i.strip() for i in z.columns]

z.sort_values(['FMonth', 'Region', 'SKU'], axis=0, ascending=[True, True, True])


Out[23]: 
   index  SKU  Region    FMonth     sh
1  20022    8      52  1/1/2013  73320
0   8264    1      67  1/1/2013  67640
3  43897    5      34  3/1/2013  98040
2  31972    3      99  3/1/2013  86320
4  55642    4      98  5/1/2013  73240
```

Comment: Yes i just need to prioritize month. And in my dataset one date is occurred  many times so your code gives output like this:

data.head()

        FMonth    sh
  2013-01-01   0.0
 2013-01-01   4.0
2013-01-01   8.0
 2013-01-01   2.0
  2013-01-01  24.0

Comment: You're putting the month as the lowest priority.  The order in the list is the priority.  
data = df.sort_values(['SKU', 'Region', 'FMonth'], axis=0, ascending=[False, True, True]).reset_index().  Should be :
data = df.sort_values(['FMonth', 'SKU', 'Region'], axis=0, ascending=[True, False, True]).reset_index()

Comment: It arranges data in ascending order but it arranges like this:
2013-01-01
2013-01-01
2013-01-01
....
2013-02-01
2013-02-01
2013-02-01
....
2013-12-01
2013-12-01
2013-12-01

And i want data to be in this order:
 2013-01-01
2013-02-01
2013-03-01
2013-04-01
...
2013-11-01
2013-12-01

To be precisely i need my data arranged in monthly order

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The months in my example are in ascending order.  The date fields are sorted automatically by Year-Month-Day.

Comment: Suppose i have one year(2013 only) of monthly data and it is arranged in 96 rows. So each date should be occurred 8 times(12*8=96).

In your code, the output is coming like Jan 2013, Jan 2013, Jan 2013, all Jan 2013, then, Feb 2013, Feb 2013, all Feb 2013, then, Mar 2013, Mar 2013, all Mar 2013,........, Dec 2013, Dec 2013, all Dec 2013.

 But i need data to be Jan 2013, Feb 2013, Mar 2013, April 2013,.....Dec 2013, then again, Jan 2013, Feb 2013, Mar 2013, April 2013,....,Dec 2013 and it continues until 95th row which is also Dec 2013. Does this help?

Comment: Your original code is exactly how you coded it.  SKU is sorted first descending (855019.133127 --> 0.000087),  then the region is sorted within that SKU ascending (3975.495636 -->   7187.170501) while the date is also sorted ascending within those groups.  This appears to be the expected behavior and I don't see any random order which you mentioned in the original post.

Comment: You <b> did </b> set SKU to descending, if that matters.  You said that you wanted them all ascending.  ascending=[False, True, True]

Comment: By random order i meant the dates are not in the ascending order in the output of data.tail() as they are in data.head() output. So dates are not ordered in the last rows of the data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried extracting the month to a new column? ```data['month'] = data['FMonth'].apply(lambda x: x.month)```